# How to exclude a package from Archunit Tests?

Tags: archunit

In my root project I have two sub projects with that package structure.

```
Project 1: com.app
Project 2: com.app.api
```

In Project 1 I have a Class definied with ArchRules, anotaed like that

```
@AnalyzeClasses( packages = "com.app")
public class ArchTests
```

The Problem is that if I run that test, its analyze everything from Project 2  too. How I can exclude package com.app.api?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use custom [importOptions](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit-junit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/junit/AnalyzeClasses.html#importOptions()):

```java
@AnalyzeClasses(packages = "com.app", importOptions = ExcludeApiImportOption.class)
```

where the [`ImportOption`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/importer/ImportOption.html) is bascially a predicate whether a [`Location`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/importer/Location.html) should be imported or not:

```java
class ExcludeApiImportOption implements com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ImportOption {
    @Override
    public boolean includes(Location location) {
        return !location.contains("com/app/api");
    }
}
```